# In this syntax, what is the actual type of auto?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++17, auto

In the C++17 for loop syntax `for(auto [key, val]: students)`, what is `auto` replacing?

If students was, for example `std::map<int,char*>`, what would be written if not `auto`? I don't understand what it even is taking the place of. `[int,char*]`?

Comment: This is called a [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding).

Comment: In that case there is no type that ```auto``` is referring.

Comment: @frozenca: Yes, there is. It's a `pair<const int, char*>`, which the value_type of the `map`.

Comment: @NicolBolas: But you cannot write `for (std::pair<const int, char*> [key, val] : students)`.

Comment: @Jarod42: True, you can't write it. But structured binding requires that there is such a type. Could be a pair, could be a tuple, but be another user-defined type. In this case, it is indeed `std::pair<const int, char*>`. Since it's a pair, you bind 2 elements.

Comment: @MSalters: Might be a wording issue. I think comment refers to *"what is `auto` replacing?"* and it cannot be replaced textually. but we agree that the type used for strutured binding is that `std::pair`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Both pieces of information are part of the answer, since the context of the original question is not fully congruent with C++ syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type [a,b,c]` is a *structured binding*, and those force you to use `auto` (possibly decorated with `const` and/or `&`/`&&`).

But aside from that, `auto` expands to the same type it would expand to if `[...]` was replaced with a variable name. In

```
for (auto elem : students)
```

... `auto` expands to `std::pair<const int, char *>`.

In a structured binding it expands to the same type, but the resulting "variable" of this type is unnamed.

Then, for each name in brackets, a reference (or something similar to a reference) is introduced, that points to one of the elements of that unnamed variable.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but thanks for the explanation. That fully clarifies the situation.

Answer (score 1):

The `std::map` is filled with `std::pair<const int, char*>`, so one way to write this loop would be

```
for (std::pair<const int, char*> pair : students)
```

We could also separate the pair with [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie), but this syntax cannot be used in the loop:

```
int key;
char* value;
std::pair<int, char*> pair;
std::tie(key, value) = pair;
```

Statement `auto [key, val]` replaces `std::tie`. This syntax is called [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding).

Comment: Observe that while the variables of a structured binding can be `const`, this would not fly for variables that are "unpacked" with `std::tie`.