# What is the 'auto' specifier extracting here?

Tags: c++

Let's say we have a `std::queue<std::pair<int, int> >`.

To extract a pair, we can either do:

```
int r = q.front().first;
int c = q.front().second;
```

or

```
auto [rr, cc] = q.front();
```

where `rr` and `cc` can then be treated as regular `int`.

I've never encountered this type of syntax before. What does the standard say about it? What is the `auto` specifier extracting?

```
auto p = q.front();
```

would just be a regular `std::pair`.

Comment: Have a look for [Structured Binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding).

Comment: This is explained in a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and various SO posts. Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"*.

Comment: @user20896951 That is exactly what I did. I searched [what does syntax auto [a,b\] mean in c++](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+does+syntax+auto+[a%2Cb]+mean+in+c%2B%2B) on google and I found [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70873747/in-this-syntax-what-is-the-actual-type-of-auto) on the first page explaining that it is called "structured bindings.".

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 2):

It's a *structured binding*, which is available since C++17.

Further reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding

Another useful place for this would be, as an example, iterating over a map. The bound variables can be references by prepending with a `&`.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::map<int, int> m { {1, 4}, {3, 7}, {4, 9} };

    for (auto &[k, v] : m) {
        std::cout << k << ": " << v << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```